# Video is not loading from youtube Playlist occasionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using YouTube API to retrieve videos from YouTube playlist using Javascript and Jquery . and showing that videos into Carousal . 
occasionally that video's loaded into carousal and sometime it's not . When i Replace the Playlist ID it works fine but after sometime i faced similar problem again.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


        function fnGoogleFeedLoaded(){  


            fnCreateCarousal(1,"2C5A4567D2B2600B");
            fnCreateCarousal(2,"9bw4S5ePsEFtdohdvpRVwqPvPorrFTQF");
            fnCreateCarousal(3,"PL9A7F57201F1AA96B");
            fnCreateCarousal(4,"88CBC02990158C01");
            fnCreateCarousal(5,"PL0155DF7A9B0DF819");
            fnCreateCarousal(6,"3367D45095D0B592");
        }
    function fnCreateCarousal(nIndex,nPlaylistID){
            var feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/"+nPlaylistID+"?max-results=8";
            new google.feeds.lookupFeed(feedUrl, function (result) {
            if (result.error || !result.url) {
                $('#videocomm').hide();
                return;
            }
            // get the feed items
            var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(result.url);
            feed.setNumEntries(50);
            feed.load(function (result) {
                // write out the feed data          
                var container = $("#CarousalBase_"+nIndex);
                //var totalcount = result.feed.entries.length;
                //alert (totalcount);
                for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                    var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
                    var vidhash = /=(.*)&(.*)$/.exec (entry.link)[1]; 

            /*      container.append('<div><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+vidhash+'" class="html5lightbox" title="'+entry.title+'"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidhash+'/0.jpg" /><br />'+entry.title+'</a></div>\n');*/

            container.append('<div><a href="#" onClick=onYouTubeIframeAPIReady("'+vidhash+'"); title="'+entry.title+'"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidhash+'/0.jpg" /><br />'+entry.title+'</a></div>\n');
                }

                // load the first video
                $(".html5lightbox:first").each(function () {
                    if(nIndex == 1){
                        loadVideo(this);
                        return false;
                    }                       
                });

                // setup the click handler for all the videso
                $(".html5lightbox").click(function () {
                    loadVideo(this);
                    return false;
                });

            });
        });     
    }


    google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
            //alert("Hii");
            fnGoogleFeedLoaded();               
    });
    google.load("feeds", "1");

  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(vidhash)
{

      player = new YT.Player('light', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: vidhash,
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });

document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 2000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
```

Comment: The YouTube API will never "ignore" HTTP requests. Even if there's an error, it will return an HTTP response back explaining what's going on. Could you please check to see what HTTP response you get back when the feed fails to load?

Comment: AFAIK, the javascript feeds API is purely asynchronous, so you could be encountering a race condition where a later request is processed before an earlier one.

Comment: hi Jeff Posnick, I checked it on Console . the HTTP Request giving me error like 

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://example.appspot.com/ from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.appspot.com. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: hi jlmcdonald . how should i encounter race condition ?